# How does one convert Sitecore JSS React boilerplate to typescript?

Tags: jss, sitecore-react, typescript

Is there a guide of some kind or possibly some helpful information floating around regarding the addition of typescript in a Sitecore `JSS` react boilerplate project?

So far I've only been able to get component code (`src/components`) to compile during local disconnected development - which is basically just relying on `create-react-app` which recognizes the `ts/tsx` extensions. I'm not able to get a prod build to work at all.

We'd like to:

- Write our react component code in typescript
- Write our Sitecore definition/manifest files in typescript
- Write root-level  scripts in typescript (`AppRoot`, `dataFetcher`, etc.)

I have found a few articles wherein people show a basic setup that compiles component typescript files but those examples are only for the component code and, in all cases, the prod build fails. The failure is caused by path/file loading when a `js` file attempts to import a ts file.

I'm assuming this is caused somewhere in the chaos of the create-react-app blackbox and the custom `webpack` configuration for `SSR` bundling. It's difficult to actually determine what is doing what between local compilation and prod build.

I've tried modifying the `server.webpack.config.js` file to utilize `ts-loader` for ts and `tsx` files but the result is the same. This is the approach I'm most familiar with as I've used it on many other projects. Of course, this would only solve the `SSR` bundling (I think??)

I've also tried adding `@babel/preset-typescript` to `sitecore/definitions/config.js` but that seems to have no affect at all.

Any help would be much appreciated. My last resort would be to start an empty create-react-app --typescript project and try to re-implement the sitecore-jss scripts and configs. I would really like to avoid that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serge van den Oever's team has built a JSS/React/TypeScript starter as part of their "JSS Umbrella" open source project. Check it out - https://github.com/macaw-interactive/react-jss-typescript-starter